# React, after deployment on netlify routes give 404 page not found on refesh

Tags: reactjs, deployment, routes, netlify

I am trying to learn how to fix the following issue.

1. After deploying my react app on netlify, when I refresh any of my routes at
   https://candid-cobbler-cd2c3e.netlify.app/ or manually load https://candid-cobbler-cd2c3e.netlify.app/red it gives me a 404 page not found error.

The site works find if I use buttons to navigate.

Solutions that I have tried so for :

1. _redirects was added to the **root** folder with `/*  /index.html  200` built and re-deployed. **Did Not Work**
2. netlify.toml was added to  **root** folder `[[redirects]] from = "/*" to = "/" status = 200`
   built and re-deployed **Did Not Work**

Take a look at my files : https://github.com/swappybizz/routing_refresh_on_deployment/

Answer (score 5):

There is a useful tutorial by hBlev : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e6qXUS3C550 where at 10:00 , it has been explained the following :

1. Netlify serves only `Index.html`
2. Everything in the `Public` directory gets build and `src` gets bundled.
3. The `_redirects` **has to be in** the `Public` directory **for the routing to work on refresh or manual loading**
4. The statement `/* /index.html 200`  is a **to** **from** **statusCode**
   and the `*` represents all possibilities and it is going to redirect them to `index.html` which is actually the only thing served. Buth the status code `200` helps keep the `/path` and **not letting it redirect** to the url but **Render while keeping the path**

details could be found [here]:https://docs.netlify.com/routing/overview/

Same site was redeployed to https://teal-mermaid-ada4e6.netlify.app
and now routes could be refreshed or directly loaded i.e by clicking https://teal-mermaid-ada4e6.netlify.app/red